# Ruby gem universal compilation for macOS

Tags: ruby, macos, github-actions

I have a ruby gem written in C which is then compiled simply like this:

```
ruby ./extconf.rb
make
```

On Windows and Linux this creates a `.so` file which I can then load in my ruby scripts.

On macOS this creates a `.bundle` file. Now `lipo -archs xxx.bundle` shows that the bundle is only for x86_64. What should I change in order to make the bundle universal for both intel-based and arm-based macOS?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
lipo -archs xxx.bundle
```

`lipo -archs` displays available architecture.

if lipo displays single architecture, you may

```bash
export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"
export CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"
export LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -arch arm64"
```

and build `.bundle` it may set universal binary compiler flags

Comment: Unfortunately lipo does show single architecture (x86_64). Adding the exports before the compilation didn't change it though.

Comment: Sorry this compiler flags are Clang compiler’s flag are you use Clang or homebrew's gcc?

Comment: I don't know. Whatever is default - we don't use any configuration to change it. I'm not experienced in C, I'm just setting up GitHub Actions for existing project.

Comment: If your environment is GitHub Actions and not MacOS, please include the contents of the GitHub Actions yaml in your question

Comment: It is macos-latest runner on GitHub Actions so it is macOS. I don't think GitHub Actions change anything in this case.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/macos-universal-binary-action) is help you?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. That action is for combining existing intel and arm binaries into a univeral one. I can do that myself using lipo. The problem is I don't know how to create an arm binary.